# Wanting to swap a hardware serial TX and RX pins (due to error in PCB design)

Tags: arduino, serial-port

This is my first post here, but i've always loved Stack overflow... this question is really getting me!

Hardware: Arduino Due

Software: Arduin IDE

Have designed, sent off, and received a few PCBs for an aruduino Cubesat project I'm working on (for uni) andddd unfortunately I mis-wired the TX and RX pins (as in, my ardunio will be receiving a TX signal on its TX1 pin, and an RX signal on its RX1 pin).

Was wondering if anyone knew a way to swap the HARDWARE serial pins around, such that the arduino TX1 and RX1 pins became RX1 and TX1 respectively. I know i can use the software serial as a hack solution, but its a little slower than I'd be happy with, so any suggestions would be awesome!

Cheers,
Jordan

Comment: use a USB 2.0 to TTL UART 6PIN Module Serial Converter, and swap wire

Comment: Cut (the traces) and jumper the PCB?

Comment: Took me a while to reply.... but @sawdust that is exactly what I did. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Nope.. You can look at the datasheet [here](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-11057-32-bit-cortex-m3-microcontroller-sam3x-sam3a_datasheet.pdf). At section 9.3.1 (PIO Controller A Multiplexing) pin PA8, which is connected to arduino PIN 0, can be mapped to URXD, PWMH0 and WKUP4, while PA9 (arduino pin 1) can be mapped to UTXD and PWMH3.

So.. No HW swapping, sorry. The only solution is to cut the traces (I suggest on your own PCB) and swap them, or to deal with the software serial (I don't think it is slow, after all you have a powerful microcontroller).

And.. Welcome in the club of the "ouch I swapped the serial pins" engineers :) I think that everybody did this at least once in his life...

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. This is exactly what I did haha.

And I've certainly learnt my lesson RE checking the serial pins before making a PCB/veroboarding!!!

Thanks :)

Comment: @JordanJolly oh, don't worry.. You can check them, recheck, check again but you'll end up swapping them ;) always... Once I had two different serial interfaces on the same PCB and I swapped them both -.- (in my defence I have to say that the producer of the two interfaces labelled the pins in two different ways)